# IOS data display and tap on it

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

[image]In my IOS project, I have to show the data in UITableView, that is suppose to be : "Team_crick_Test" won the cricket match "C4 cricket" against "Bengal Tigers cricket Club". Now when I tap on "Team_crick_Test"/ "C4 cricket", it will redirect to it's team page. In this scenario how should I display the data in UITableView? And how should I tap on "Team_crick_Test" /"C4 cricket"?

My requirement is very much similar data display in Facebook wall. If possible, please provide a sample of code.

Comment: What you want , the question is not clear, You should have to decide what design is in your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is logical implementation. We have multiple options for it.

1) Draw the complete text and with normal and highlighted colours. redirect with hi-lighted coloured text with touch events of view.

2) By using `NSAttributedString` of UILabel redirect to link.

3) take an  `UIWebview` and load `HTML` page on it and redirect with links using `Webview` delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following delegate method,when when you tapped on a row in table view this method will be called

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```